# Deploying my Web Application without changing Paths

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In my web application I'm currently developing I have a `ASP.NET Web API` project for my backend and another project for my frontend (`AngularJS`). My backend is running on *localhost:1337* and my frontend on *localhost:1338*. This works perfectly fine, but I'm having troubles deploying it to my webserver.

In my frontend, I have the base  `localhost:1337` declared, but this does not work on the server (which I understand). I would need to change the path before deploying it, so my frontend calls the API on the server.

My question is: Is there any way around changing those parts? Would it be a better idea to deploy the backend onto the server everytime I commit something and then call it directly from the server in my frontend?

**EDIT:**

Some more information on how I am doing it:
In Visual Studio I set the local project URL in the properties of my projects to those specific urls. To make theses calls, somewhere in my javascript I have a BaseUrl like `var BaseUrl = "localhost:1337";` and I am making all the HttpRequests to my API with this "hardcoded" URL. This url for example would have to be changed everytime I deploy.

How I deploy: Right click on the project in VS -> Publish and then I have a specific profile for both projects. They are both deployed correctly to the server.

Comment: Please explain how you "have the base localhos:1337 declared", and what steps tou're taking to deploy your site. Without that information it's impossible to hlep you.

Comment: Allright, i will do an edit, give me a second

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions:

- deploy a different file depending on the solution configuration (for example, if you're using bundles, you can use variables to include different scripts in the different bundles)
- intercept the request for the .js file and modify it on the fly using some configuration file. A variant of this is serving you .js file from an MVC action or an `.aspx` or `.asmx`. Your browser doesn't require the `.js` extension at all.
- use a post-build script to modify the .js file

As you don't give more specific information, I simply show some possible solutions.